# Angular material mat-sidenav

Tags: angular

I am currently following a tutorial about angular material. The tutorial has code as follows:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container" >
    <mat-sidenav opened mode="side">Start content</mat-sidenav>
    Implicit main content
    <mat-sidenav opened  mode="side" position="end">End content</mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>

<p>Please open on Stackblitz to see result</p>
```

According to the tutorial everything should appear. However, when I try to implement the same code nothing appears on my browser, including the text inside the `<p>` tag. However, whenever I remove the `<mat-sidenav>` tag then everything appears.

I would like to know, why is that the case?

Thank you

Comment: please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-drawer-overview-example.ts

Comment: Please note that I've only removed the `*ngIf` decorator

Comment: Your stackblitz is not having any code, could you check the link shared?

Comment: Tried you're code and seems to be working as expected. See the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztjzqz?file=src/app/sidenav-overview-example.html

Comment: Check if there are any other compilation errors

Comment: This is the stackblitz code, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atvkn8?file=src/app/sidenav-overview-example.ts

Comment: @AnjulaRanasinghe I can see that it is working on stackblitz, but it is not working on my local machine and my code compiled successfully

Comment: check your dom in the elements tab in dev tools... check your console...

Comment: @Exception good recommendation. I just did and the content of `mat-sidenav-container` is not visible. It is only visible when ever I remove the `mat-sidenav`

Comment: Fixed it. I just needed the `BrowserAnimationModule` module for rendering animation in my browser. Thanks to everyone who tried assisting.